# What is SVM regression? Is it for regression or classification?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, nonlinear-regression, computational-statistics

I'm trying to understand what is SVM regression. It's used for classification or regression?
Can someone give an intuitive understanding of it?

Comment: it's for regression. It uses the hinge loss function: points inside a small stab around the regression manifold are not penalized.

Comment: Hmm, it gives prediction for the point outside of the small stab also ?

Comment: @user2806363 yes it does.

Answer (score -2):

There is a [presentation](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/courses/cap6412/fall2009/papers/Berwick2003.pdf) on SVMs that does quite a good job of providing an intuitive explanation.  To simplify, the basic idea is to find a line (or a hyperplane in multivariate models) that separates the data.  The main difference with OLS is that not all points influence the fit of the line/hyperplane.  Only a subset of training points "close" to the line (the support vectors), influence the "fit".

SVMs are applied to datasets that can't be seperated by straight lines (including classification problems) by applying [kernel functions](http://crsouza.blogspot.co.nz/2010/03/kernel-functions-for-machine-learning.html).

Comment: Your answer is not answering the actual question.